# Geocoding town names to their coordinates in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, google-maps-markers, geocoding

I've read similar posts, but still didn't find a solution for myself. Basically I have an array with countries+towns in PHP and I need to show them on the map with markers. Here is my code:

```
function showAddress(markers) {

    var address = "<?php echo $Fcity[$j], " , ", $Fcountry[$j]?>";
     if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
            if (!point) {
              alert(address + " not found");
            } else {

            var marker = new GMarker(point);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            markers[i] = marker;        
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);

            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

Everything seems to work if I geocode one location, but I can't put it into a loop to process all of them.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            showAddress(markers[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Ugh, do people really do this? Interlace PHP and JavaScript? This is really messy... I would suggest assigning PHP to Javascript variables somewhere, and then doing logic on the Javascript variables. This code is going to be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

In your showAddress function, you reference markers[i].

However, you don't pass in i... that variable is not in the scope of the function. So, you aren't iterating and adding, you are adding variables over and over to a non-existent place in the array.

You either need to pass in i or not encapsulate showAddress in a function.

How about making the function showAddresses and putting the loop in the function.

Comment: I have tried that, but it didnt help, even if put just a number in "i<   "

function showAddress(address) {
for($i=0;$i< "<?php echo $data?>";$i++){
 var address = "<?php echo $city, " , ", $country?>";
   if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
            if (!point) {
              alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
              map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
              marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
       }
          }
          }
        );
      }
    }